# Can't configure NGINX to cache the images

Tags: linux, caching, ubuntu, nginx

I have been trying to cache images that are stored in nginx server, I am quite new to nginx I have installed it and configure it with php5-fpm, I have been reading many tutorial regarding caching images and php files. I have succeeded in caching the PHP files but I can't cache the images here is part of the nginx config file:

```
fastcgi_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=MYAPP:100m inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;
add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

server {    
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html index.htm;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name localhost;

set $skip_cache 0;

# POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
if ($request_method = POST) {
    set $skip_cache 1;
}   
if ($query_string != "") {
    set $skip_cache 1;
}   

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}  

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_cache MYAPP;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;

}

location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ {
    access_log off; log_not_found off; expires 1d;
}

location ~ /\. { deny  all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }
}
```

now when I run `curl -I http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/script.php` I can see the md5 of the script created in `/etc/nginx/cache` folder and I can see the `X-Cache : HIT`

However, when I run `curl -I http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/image.jpg` no file created in the `/etc/nginx/cache` and I have the following result in the console:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 17 Jun 2014 08:14:37 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 55936
Last-Modified: Tue, 17 Jun 2014 04:30:11 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "539fc453-da80"
Expires: Wed, 18 Jun 2014 08:14:37 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

now it looks fine however when I run it again the expiry date will keep changing as if it is calling new image not the cache

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 17 Jun 2014 08:16:34 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 55936
Last-Modified: Tue, 17 Jun 2014 04:30:11 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "539fc453-da80"
Expires: Wed, 18 Jun 2014 08:16:34 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

my questions are:

1- should the cached images be shown in the cache folder?

2- does `fastcgi` capable of caching the images?

3- what can I do to fix the image caching problem?

Sorry for the beginner questions, but I can't find the answer.

Comment: Images are static, nginx isn't supossed to cache static files since there is no processing overhead to serve them, just add expire time and your're set.

Comment: This is the kind of cache you want for your images: http://tomayko.com/writings/things-caches-do

Comment: @ManuelGutierrez Thanks for your response and please bare with me as I am new at this, Now I have added the expire time for 1 day, I run the curl for the image and I get the expiry date. When I run the curl again the expiry date changes, isn't suppose to take the expiry date of the first one? (you can see as shown in the output above).

Comment: curl doesn't has a cache like a browser, every request is like the first time, so nginx sends the expire time since that precise moment, try a recent Firefox and use Ctrl+Shift+I > Network and hit F5 to see how the cache works.

Comment: @MGP sorry but you are wrong; what if images are resized or generated? They really do not have to be static files.

Comment: @KirillG. In such case I'd say the fastcgi_cache will work, because images will be returned by the fastcgi block (e.g. a dynamic response), but op images are being returned by a different `location` block which finds them as static files.